# Frame box around the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, framed, box

I'm trying to put a frame box around ALL e table of contents in an `article` document class.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBoHC.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how big your ToC is, the following works without any packages (`duckuments` is only loaded to quickly produce a few pages of contents with sections and subsections).

### Small ToC (no need for column or page breaks)

This solution will only work as long as your ToC fits on a single page/in a single column.

You can change the rule thickness of the box by using `\setlength{\fboxrule}{<your length>}`, and change the distance between the frame and the contents by using `\setlength{\fboxsep}{<your length>}` (best done in a group around `\fbox` to not change anything else in the document, *e.g.*, `\begingroup\setlength{\fboxrule}{1cm}\fbox{...}\endgroup`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fbox
  {%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      \tableofcontents
    \end{minipage}%
  }%

\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Bigger ToC (or fancy boxes)

If your ToC requires to be page breakable, you can use the `tcolorbox` package and its `breakable` library. The following is an example which uses the default looks of a `tcolorbox` (but `tcolorbox` is *really* customisable, so you can achieve almost any looks you could imagine with this, this includes a plain looking frame as done with `\fbox`)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
  \tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}

\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much!